# How do I reassign even and odd indices of a character array into a new smaller character array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, char, indices

In matlab I have a 32x1 character array A such that

```
A = {'F1' 'F2' 'F3' 'F4' 'F5' 'F6' ... 'F32'};
A = A';
```

Now I am trying to do the following with A. 
For every even index of A meaning

`A{2}, A{4}, A{6}...`

I want to assign those values to a 16x1 character array B and for the odd indices of A I want to assign those values to a different 16x1 array C.

I use the following code:

```
for i=1:32
 if mod(i,2)==0
   B{i} = A{i};
 else
   C{i} = A{i};
 end
end
```

and it works, but only partially because it assigns the right values at for e.g. `B{2} and B{4}` but the values in `B{1} and B{3}` are the same as in `B{2} and B{4}`.

Can anybody tell me how to reassign even and odd indices of a character array into a new smaller character array? My problem is that I am going from a 32x1 into a 16x1 and I'm not sure how to avoid the extra 16 entries.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not just `B = A(2:2:end); C = A(1:2:end);` ?

Comment: Tried it before posting this but it didn't work, as @thewaywewalk suggested with `deal` worked though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this question actual answered, use the idea of Luis Mendo in the comments. You can combine it with [**`deal`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) to save one line of code:

```
[B, C] = deal(A(2:2:end), A(1:2:end))
```

To make your loop work, you need a second running index `jj`:

```
A = {'F1' 'F2' 'F3' 'F4' 'F5' 'F6'};

for ii = 1:6
     jj = ceil(ii/2);
     if mod(ii,2)==0
        B{jj} = A{ii};
     else
        C{jj} = A{ii};
     end
end
```

Comment: thanks so much, didn't know `deal` existed.. now I do! thanks a bunch